Show the higher value typed from an input
I'm learning Python and I have this exercise to do:
The code need to show the highest typed number (8 inputs) to the user. This is what I have:
for i in range (1,9):
    number = int (input("Type a number: "))

I'm struggling on the print part.

Not entirely sure about what are you looking for, but I believe this is closer to what you want
list_of_numbers = []

for i in range(0,8): #It must start in 0, since 8 wont be taken
   list_of_numbers.append(int(input("Type a number: ")))

print(max(list_of_numbers)) #I guess you to print it at the end


@WesleyCardoso If their answer helped you, please press that check mark to the left of this answer to show other people that you aren't still looking for another answer.

You have to have an var to store the lowest number before you loop:
b = input("Higher number we need: ")
for i in range(0,8):
  a = input("Type a number: ")
  if b > a 
     continue
print a

If you want to get a highest number in the entered values you may do this:
b = input("Higher number we need: ")
for i in range(0,8):
  a = input("Type a number: ")
  if b > a 
     continue
  else
     b = a
print b


There are several ways to do this. An easy one would be to have a max_number variable that you update with the new highest value each time the user inputs a number. You can look up the max() function, it could help with what you are trying to achieve.
Side note, if you want to actually have 8 user inputs, you must change your range(1, 8) to range(8) or range(1, 9) since the former will only go from 1 to 7 included (the range() function will not include the stopping number).
